# Right place to call REST service in fragment lifecycle

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

What is the best place in fragment lifecycle to call REST service for example to fill `ListView` with received data ? There are `onCreateView`, `onActivityCreated` and `onResume`. My first thought was to call network service as soon as possible, so on the end `onCreateView`, but i'm confused about this.

Comment: Do you want it every time the app comes to the foreground? Use onResume()
Do you want it only when the app starts for the first time? Use onViewCreated(), this is called after onCreateView is finished.

Comment: @marioosh: you should accept Oleg's answer. he provided you link to the best Google IO discussion ever made addressing exactly that issue.

Comment: I don't want to call the rest API inside my fragment when I come back to the fragment from another activity. in which method I should do the API call ?

Answer (score 2):

Just don't bind REST calls to your UI. You should split up UI and business logic responsible for getting and updating data. UI is just a facade so you shouldn't try to call any network services from UI. You can implement any of the patterns described by Virgil Dobjanshi in [IO Talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE)

Comment: I have no problem with this. I'm using [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) and [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). More preciously - my question would be: in which method of fragment lifecycle i should call `bus.post(new GetSomeDataFromNetworkEvent());`

Comment: If I were you I would use onResume(). But also I would consider using RxJava for Android https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid - Retrofit fully supports it. Using Retrofit + RxJava you are completely avoiding all lifecycle headache. More on this topic https://www.parleys.com/talk/5471cdd1e4b065ebcfa1d557/chapter0/about